# how to change xaml c# Metro App theme

Tags: c#-4.0, winrt-xaml

I am trying to make an app with XAML and C#, but i do not know how to change the theme, i google a lot and found this thing

```
//App.xaml.cs
public App()
{
this.InitializeComponent();
App.Current.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light; //theme changed to light,but still blacks
this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
}
```

Please help me with this requested theme!

Comment: have you tried to set theme via xaml ?

Comment: Did you see this [post](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/01/walkthrough-dynamically-skinning-your.html)?